# Subversion Permission Denied when adding or committing

Tags: linux, permissions, svn

I am running subversion 1.4 on Centos 5.2 and my clients are using tortoise to do their check out, commit etc. I think I have permissions problems but I have configured the folder to accessible to everyone with 777 attribute but I seem not to be getting anywhere. Its generating this error on tortoise "svn: Can't open file 'PATH/TO/MY/FILES/entries': Permission denied". Some guy was suggesting some indexing software installed on the client machine like google desktop, any suggestions?

Comment: Is Subversion running through Apache or svnserve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is with samba, after a long grill with permissions we discovered that for some reason you need to add these entries in the smb.conf file.

force create mode = 0774
delete readonly = yes

I know to some of you it might sound crazy considering that you have the write permission enable already, it think its a bug!!LoL :)

Comment: First of all, I want to hug Rungano for pointing me in the right direction. His answer also takes care of a simular problem: If you are developing on a local development server and use samba mounts to reach your working copy, you can get in trouble with files inside the .svn folder getting permissions that are too restrictive. This will wreck merge, update and commit operations. The same solution applies. Again, thanks a million Rungano.

Answer (score 2):

One thing note, If a parent folder does not grant traverse permission (the execute flag x), then non-root users will get an error message, even if the leaf directory node is set to 777. Also, if you are using Apache, you will need to make sure that there is  config block that allows access to your files.